# How to detect key press signal inside if statement and place inside it's own thread PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm having trouble figuring out how to detect key press signal inside of an if statement that's in another class and thread and thus try to also place the key press signal emit/receive inside it's own thread PyQt5.

The window class handles the gui stuff, but then the modbusworker class has is its thread to handle the exiting. Basically when I click run the script starts collecting and saving data from an Arduino. However, I would like a keyboard hotkey (return key) that can trigger additional print statements for labeling. Integrating this has been my issue.

Thanks!

```
class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.m_thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
    self.m_thread.start()

    self.m_modbus_worker = ModbusWorker()
   # self.m_modbus_worker.connect()
    self.m_modbus_worker.moveToThread(self.m_thread)

    btn = self.pushButton_11
    btn.clicked.connect(Window.restart)
    btn_ex = self.pushButton_12  # exit button
    btn_ex.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stop())

    #btn_ex.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stopIt())
    self.show()

    # self.UIcomp()
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.b1())
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b2())
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b3())
    self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b4())
    self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b5())
    self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b6())
    self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b7())
    self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b8())
    self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.b9())

    self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.start())

    keyPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    super(Window, self).keyPressEvent(event)
    self.keyPressed.emit(event.key())
    #somehow this needs to be part of its known thread

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def start(self):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.m_modbus_worker.do_work)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def stop(self):
    self.m_thread.requestInterruption()



class ModbusWorker(QtCore.QObject):   

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def do_work(self):

      
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        arduino_port = "/dev/tty.usbmodem2101"  # serial port of Arduino
     #   baud = 115200
        baud = 9600
        # name of the CSV file generated
        fileName = b1file + now.strftime("%m %d %Y, %H:%M:%S ") + ".csv"
        ser = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baud)
        print("Connected to Arduino port:" + arduino_port)

      

        print("Created file")

        file = open("/Users/Documents/" + fileName, "w+")
        file.write(now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S "))
        file.write(b1title)

        while not QtCore.QThread.currentThread().isInterruptionRequested():


            #Not sure what to do here to check the signal
            #if (signal detected):
            #     write...

            getData = str(ser.readline())
            data = getData[2:][:-7]
          

            # add the data to the file
            # append the data to the file
           # file.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            print(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            file.write(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            print(data)
            file.write(data + "\n")  # write data with a newline

    
        QtCore.QThread.currentThread().quit()
  


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()

    Window.restart()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You need to define a slot for the worker that can be connected to the `keyPressed` signal. The slot can then set an attribute with the key which can be polled inside `do_work`.

Comment: `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
`

So I get this part, but could you clarify in terms of code how it would look? I've been trying different things for a while and I'm quite lost on what it should look like.

Comment: Just define a new slot ***for the worker***, as I described above. I can't really explain it more simply: `self.keyPress.connect(self.m_modbus_worker.mynewslot)`.

Comment: Ok I see, but all the documentation I see for slots defines them as functions, like 
`def sayHello():
 6  print 'Hello world!'
`
But I'm just trying to check if the signal has been sent without calling a function like .mynewslot. Also, its inside of a live while loop so I don't think even if I had another function in the ModbusWorker class that it could update a variable that I can check in inside the live loop to indicate the key is clicked.

Comment: Wow, you really are making hard work of this. (1) Under `ModbusWorker`, add e.g. `@QtCore.pyqtSlot() def mynewslot(self, key): self.key = key`. (2) Connect this slot to the signal: `self.keyPress.connect(self.m_modbus_worker.mynewslot)`. (3) Poll the key inside the loop: `if self.key == whatever: # do something`.

Comment: Well, you obviously must give `self.key` a default value, since you're waiting for the user to press a key.

Comment: Didn't mean to delete my last comment woops. Where do I set the default value for self.key? Inside mynewslot?

Comment: And how do I change the key value because self.keyPress.connect(self.m_modbus_worker.mynewslot) doesn't take another parameter

Comment: No, just set it to zero or something in `__init__`. You can define the signal in whatever way you want. Please consult some basic python and pyqt tutorials.